# Using in memory context in service layer unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a service called UserService (this is obviously made up)

```
private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

public UserService(
    IUserRepository userRepository,
    IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _authenticationService = authenticationService;
}

public async Task UpdateUser(UserDTO userDTO)
{
    var authenticationDetails = await _authenticationService.Authenticate(userDTO.Id);

    if (authenticationDetails.Success)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetUser(userDTO.Id);
        user.Update(userDTO);

        _userRepository.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The IUserRepository implementation looks like this:

```
public UserRepository : Repository
{
    private readonly UserContext _userContext;

    public UserRepository(UserContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _userContext = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

What I want to do, is have two service tests like these:
**UpdateUser_WithSuccessfulAuthentication_UpdatesUser**
**UpdateUser_WithFailedAuthentication_DoesNothing**

If following correct unit testing principles, I want to only consider the output (in this case, check if the user has been updated).
This way I can test the business logic inside the service method UpdateUser (which in this case is that single condition that checks if the user is authenticated. In reality there might be some more complex logic).

**Currently I have considered one option for this, but haven't been able to make it work:**

I can mock the IAuthenticationService using Moq, and have an in-memory-database context that would be used for the IUserRepository. So the first unit test would look something like this:

```
public void UpdateUser_WithSuccessfulAuthentication_UpdatesUser()
{
    // Arrange
    var authenticationServiceMock = new Mock<IAuthenticationService>(); 
    var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserContext>()
          .UseInMemoryDatabase("Db")
          .Options;

    using var context = new UserContext(contextOptions);
    var userRepository = new UserRepository(context);

    var userService = new UserService(userRepository, authenticationServiceMock.Object);
    
    ... setup the authentication service methods, in this case Authenticate

    var userDTOToCreate = GetUserTestDoubleToCreate();
    var userDTOToUpdate = GetUserTestDoubleToUpdate();

    userRepository.Insert(userDTOToCreate);
    
    // Act
    userService.UpdateUser(userDTOToUpdate);

    // Assert
    ... assert user was updated etc.

}
```

The problem with this is I cannot use the context inside this service since it has already been disposed.

I have no other ideas on how to do this.

Comment: The entire design has problems. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a multi-entity *repository* and Unit of Work. A DbSet is a single-entity repository. All those IRepository classes and implementations put a low-level abstraction over a higher level abstraction. Worse, methods like `UpdateUser` break the Unit-of-Work behavior *completely*. DbContext tracks all tracking changes and saves all of them in a single database transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. To "rollback", just don't call `SaveChanges`. Calling it after every operation prevents you from rolling back

Comment: As for `I cannot use the context inside this service since it has already been disposed.` that's not what the code shows. In `UpdateUser_WithSuccessfulAuthentication_UpdatesUser` the UserContext is declared at the very top and disposed only when the method exits. There's no other `using` or `Dispose()`

Comment: You didn't post any code that adds users to the database. What does `_userRepository.GetUser(userDTO.Id);` return? Are you sure `user.Update` works? Is `authenticationDetails.Success` false perhaps? The relevant code is missing from the question so it's impossible to reproduce the problem. There are many things that could result in no changes to the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
About the user setup, yes I did miss it (will add)
Ultimately not adding the user isn't what is failing. I don't seem to be able to call any UserRepository methods from my created UserService in the test, since it throws
 ObjectDisposedException

Comment: Where does it throw that? What's the call stack at this point? What is the actual *full* exception text? The code posted here doesn't dispose the DbContext until *after* the test ends. If `Repository` tries to dispose the DbContext itself without checking to see if it's already disposed you *could* get such an exception after the test ends. Adding all those little repositories over the big repository doesn't help in anything but it *does* make it a lot harder to maintain the code. Or ask for help without posting a lot of infrastructure code

Comment: The full exception text ie the text returned by Exception.ToString() contains the actual location where the error occurred, any inner exceptions and the stack trace that shows the chain of calls that resulted in the exception. During debugging you can get the full text by clicking on `Copy Details` in Visual Studio's exception popup